# Unity 3D - Rotate towards object with random offsets

Tags: unity, rotation, vector, quaternion

Title is a little confusing, but let me explain:

I want to make the enemies look at the player, and shoot at him, with random precision, meaning that one time the enemy will shoot a little bit to the left of the player, next time a little bit to the right of him, and sometimes exactly at him.

Currently I have this scene:
[image]

The turret rotates, and when the green direction spots the player, it shoots a bullet facing the player (the green arrow).

Now I need where the rotation is passed for the `Instantiate`, to have some random precision, and I don't know how to do it. Here's what I have so far

```
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(firingPoint.transform.position.x, firingPoint.transform.position.y, firingPoint.transform.position.z);

float playerX = playerObject.transform.position.x;
float playerY = playerObject.transform.position.y;
float playerZ = playerObject.transform.position.z;

float randomX = Random.Range(playerX - 1f, playerX + 1f);
float randomY = Random.Range(playerY - 1f, playerY + 1f);
float randomZ = Random.Range(playerZ - 1f, playerZ + 1f);    

Quaternion aimPrecision = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(randomX, randomY , randomZ));

Instantiate(bulletPrefab, pos, aimPrecision);
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: Right now, the enemy shoots like this:
[image]

but never towards me, or backwards

Comment: Does it not work for you? Why?

Comment: The enemy shoots at random directions up, left, right, and down, but never towards me

Comment: look at the edit please

Comment: Will it work if you don't randomize the rotation?

Comment: if I pass in the default values of playerObject (x, y and z) the enemy shoots only to the left, or only up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Here's what I've done:

I took the default forward rotation of the `firingPoint` object, and split it into it's parts - `x, y, z, w`.

Then from these floats, I create a new `Quaternion` using the constructor method:

```
float randomX = Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f);
float randomY = Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f);
float randomZ = Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f);
float randomW = Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f);

Quaternion oldRot = firingPoint.rotation;
Quaternion newRot = new Quaternion(oldRot.x + randomX, oldRot.y + randomY, oldRot.z + randomZ, oldRot.w + randomW);
```

Then every time this code get's called, the object will be instantiated with random rotation facing the player.